# Understanding Y U Egorov's theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators, canonical-transformation

I was reading the paper 
"*Hörmander, L.*, [**Fourier integral operators. I**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392052), Acta Math. 127, 79-183 (1971). [ZBL0212.46601](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0212.46601)." and on page 3, there is a statement saying the following thing:[image]

Can someone explain what exactly is given by Egorov's theorem? I found the original paper by Egorov from the given reference but it is written in Russian (which I cannot read). Also, if $PA=AQ$, what is the exact relation between the principal symbols of $P$ and $Q$?